# Kinect problem - [/openni_camera] No devices connected

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, robot-calibration, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, there,
I'm trying to connect Kinect with turtlebot, but it is not working. First of all, I was following instructions on how to "hack" kinect cable and connect it with power board which has gyro. I cut power cable as it was shown and made an adapter to connect with power board. Then, I've connected Kinect with my TrimSlice - I see green light on Kinect start blinking. I've plugged second cable into the power board and run:
roslaunch turtlebot_calibration calibrate.launch
After all processes has started I consistently see:

[INFO] [WallTime: 1321466338.673699] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321466338.975991] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321466339.277746] Still waiting for scan
[INFO] [WallTime: 1321466339.580285] Still waiting for scan
[ INFO] [1321466339.599740633]: [/openni_camera] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
...

Ctrl+C doesn't stop this process and I would have this output unless I will kill this  process.

I was searching by error in google and here but didn't get anything which I could apply to my situation. Most of the questions about Kinect related to it work when I can't even start it. Any ideas what I was doing wrong or/and how I can fix it? Thanks.
-Roman.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11968/kinect-problem---%5B/openni_camera%5D-no-devices-connected/) by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2011-11-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on 2011-11-21**:
I don't know how but it finaly got through. I was trying many different things and appently one of them has worked. Now I'm getting different errors but this is a subject for a separate topic. Thanks!

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-11-16**:
can you view images out of the kinect? that would be the first thing to check. when the calibration says waiting for scan, a scan is not being published which could mean in turn that a pointcloud isn't being published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can you view images out of the kinect? that would be the first thing to check. when the calibration says waiting for scan, a scan is not being published which could mean in turn that a pointcloud isn't being published

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0